# Desktop files disappeared mysteriously. Entire directory missing

Tags: ubuntu, desktop

My desktop files on Ubuntu disappeared mysteriously when I tried to drag and drop files to my pen drive. I tried all options available on stack exchange and elsewhere on the internet, like reinstalling compiz, gnome, searching the directory name prefixed with a dot and also searching for the hidden files and folders, but nothing really worked. Any idea of how I could recover them? I do not have a backup setup unfortunately and I have all my important data stored on it. Please help!!!

Comment: Have you tried opening a terminal and doing an `ls -l ~/Desktop` to see if things are actually still there?

Comment: Yes, I did try that option. There are no files on the ~/Desktop folder unfortunately.

Comment: The files that disappeared, are these the the files you dragged and dropped to your pen drive? Did you probably move instead of copy those files?

Comment: @Dubu: Yes. But in that case, its not on my pen drive too.

Comment: what did you do ? `history` command can list your shell history which can help you locate the problem. I came across a similar case whose root cause may be different. Once I installed 'Mendeley Desktop', when I uninstalled it , I want to remove all configuration files, then I exec 'find -iname "*mendeley*" | xargs rm -rf', here xargs didn't process the very case in which filename contains space, which "Mendeley Desktop" folder will be treated as 'rm -rf Mendely; rm -rf Desktop'. Then I realized I should   append -0 parameter to handle this specific case. Hope my answer can help you.

Comment: Next time, use the command line. Avoid spaces in file (& directory) names; prefer an underscore `_`

Answer (score 2):

You must have dropped the folder into some other folder while dragging it. Just check all the possible folders.Use the find command to find it.

```
find . -name filename
```

example:

```
find . -name jar
```

Comment: @cuonglm: I tried that option as well, I couldn't find it.

Comment: you might replace the `.`  with `/home`

Answer (score 1):

Use `testdisk` to find and recover lost files and directories. It will be able to identify deleted files, meaning you should potentially be able to recover deleted files from either your hard drive or the pen drive or any other storage medium if they were ever written to it.

This [recovery guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT) details usage for FAT filesystems (likely the filesystem type of your pen drive). As with all recovery operations, install the program and recover your files to a different partition than the one you are trying to recover files from, and don't write anything new to the drive until you have recovered all that you are going to recover.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.