# Files mysteriously disappearing

Tags: files

Today, I opened my music player to play a particular song, and couldn't find it. So I check the filesystem - the entire folder for that album is missing. I did a count of the entire contents of the directory - 226 total files there. Yesterday there were 228. What happened to them? I definitely didn't delete them.

This sounds very similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199549/desktop-files-disappeared-mysteriously-entire-directory-missing), except that I don't drag and drop things - I exclusively use the command line. Their problem happened when trying to drag and drop (i.e. move) a folder, while my files vanishes without me doing anything involving them. I don't even know what the other missing folder was - I don't remember the names of all 228 folders, so all I know is that one is missing, not which one it is. Is there any way to find *that* out?

I also noticed that my s.m.a.r.t check is reporting a high reallocated sector count, implying that my disk might be failing soon - is it possible that disappearing files are a symptom of incipient disk failure?

Comment: What file systems are you using? Are there any warning messages in `dmesg`? You can try to run a undelete tool to see if it was accidentally deleted. Search for .mp3 you are missing - maybe it was moved accidentally somewhere else.

Comment: Filesystems are built to *store files long term*, mysteriously disappearing files are an extremely bad bug, unlikely to survive for any length of time. *Something* (or *somebody*) deleted those files, perhaps by accident (files routinely moved/deleted by the system definitely don't include user files like the ones mentioned).

Comment: @jofel dmesg is really big, and there's a lot of stuff in it I don't recognize. How would I recognize an error? I don't know of an undelete tool would help - I use the command line, so I use "rm" instead of drag-to-trash, and my understanding was that you couldn't undelete rm?

Comment: @vonbrand No kidding! How do I figure out what what deleted it?

Comment: Search for the format of your filesystem (probably `ext3` or `ext4`) and/or the name of you disk (like `sda1`, `sdb3` ...). Both are usually displayed if you call `mount` without any parameter. Look also for I/O errors. Was the system properly restarted since yesterday or where there a sudden power-off etc.?

Comment: @jofel Ok, I do see a line with "4 orphan inodes deleted" - looks like there were errors causing it to re-mount the drive.

Comment: Use `testdisk` to navigate directories and recover lost files and directories. I recently had a recurring bug which deleted an important folder multiple times (cause still unknown), but testdisk was able to identify the deleted folder and restore it to another partition. The [recovery guide here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_ext2 "recovery guide here") (written for ext2) works essentially the same for ext4. Journaling filesystems like ext3 and ext4 should have decent error correction mechanisms in case of power failure, etc., but the safest thing is to keep one or

Comment: I eventually "solved" this problem by replacing the drive, so I guess it was a hardware thing. Although I would still appreciate someone explaining how it happened?